# Use matplotlib Axes autoscaling without plotting anything

Tags: python, matplotlib

matplotlib does a good job of picking axis limits based on the data you throw at it.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(0)
y = np.random.normal(size=37, loc=2, scale=1.5)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax1.plot(y)
ax2.plot(y * 328)
fig.tight_layout()
```

Results in:
[image]

Both axes are scaled in a sane matter based on both the range and order of magnitude of the data.

#### Question

How do I learn what those limits would be, or even apply them to an existing Axes object without actually drawing anything on it?

`ax.update_datalim` seemed promising, but doesn't seem to do what I hoped:

```
x = np.array([0] * y.shape[0])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.update_datalim(list(zip(x, y)), updatex=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be what you were looking for? Unsure if you were wanting to update the x-axis or not or just the y-axis limits without plotting.

```
np.random.seed(0)
y = np.random.normal(size=37, loc=2, scale=1.5)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
x = np.array([0] * y.shape[0])
ax1_lim = ((0, min(y)), (len(x), max(y)))
ax2_lim = ((0, min(y) * 328), (len(x), max(y) * 328))
ax1.update_datalim(ax1_lim)
ax2.update_datalim(ax2_lim)
ax1.autoscale()
ax2.autoscale()
```

Comment: Ahh, it's the call to `autoscale` that I'm missing.